# How to place icons side by side with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am looking to use media-queries to place my FA icons side by side, when the screen width is below 544px in a nav bar type effect.

I have generated the media queries, as seen below:

```
/* Media Query for Sidebar */
/* For larger screens */
@media (min-width: 545px) {
span.icon {
    display: inline-block;
}

span.text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar {
    position: static;
}
}

/* Smaller screens */
@media (max-width: 544px) {
span.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

span.text {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar {
    position: relative;
}

.dashContent {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
}
```

The current result I am getting would be similar to this: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKZkB.png)

My HTML Markup is here

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <nav class="nav flex-column sidebar">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar icon"></i> <span class="text">Dashboard</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs icon"></i> <span class="text">My Profile</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-users icon"></i> <span class="text">Users</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> <span class="text">Subjects</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <span class="text">Bookings</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i> <span class="text">Reviews</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i> <span class="text">Messages</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> <span class="text">Support</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link text-danger" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt icon"></i> <span class="text">Logout</span></a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="dashContent">
            <p>Dashboard content should show up here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing when using these media queries to align them?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the screen tag to your media query, like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 544px) {
 ...
}
@media screen and (min-width: 545px) {
 ...
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing the functionality working:
https://jsfiddle.net/8329pjk9/3/

Comment: Still no luck with this solution sadly